# Unable to align text in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to React Native. I have created a login page with it. I want to know how I can align the `Login` text on the left side instead of showing it in the center.

[image]

My code:

**Login.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TextInput, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const Login = () => {

  return (

     <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.head}>
             Login
        </Text>
        <TextInput placeholder="Username" style={styles.input}/>
        <TextInput placeholder="Password" style={styles.input}/>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
            <Text style={styles.textStyle}>LOGIN</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor:'white'
},
head:{
   alignItems:'flex-start',
   fontWeight:'bold',
   fontSize:30,
   marginBottom:15
},
input:{
    height:50,
    borderRadius:5,
    backgroundColor:'#ededed',
    alignSelf:'stretch',
    marginLeft:15,
    marginRight:15,
    marginBottom:8,
    paddingLeft:15
},
button:{
    backgroundColor:'#e57373',
    alignSelf:'stretch',
    borderRadius:5,
    marginLeft:15,
    marginRight:15,
    alignItems:'center',
    padding: 15,
},
textStyle:{
    fontWeight:'bold',
    color:'white'
}
});

export default Login;
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong in the code above.

Comment: Try alignSelf:'flex-start' on .head instead of alignItems:'flex-start'

Comment: Could you plz tell what's the difference between `stretch` and `flex-start`.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_align-items&preval=stretch

Comment: align-items works on the element that is set as display flex... Align-self works on the child of flex element. Like in your case the container was flex and the Login heading was a child of flex element.

Comment: Sorry but I suggest using textAlign: 'left' instead of using alignSelf, as it is just a Text component.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now, but it should be something like this:

Add the `alignSelf` and `textAlign` attributes to your `head`-styles.

```
head: {
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 30,
    marginBottom: 15,
    textAlign: 'left'
},
```

Comment: @NanditaSharma: It's fine to elevate an answer posted as a comment to a new answer. That way, ideally, the OP can mark the answer as accepted. (That said, when I copy an answer from the comments, I usually mark it as a community wiki.)

Comment: I don't get what you try to say... The answer is neither copied, nor equal to the one in the comments 

Answer (score 0):

alignItems is concerned with the children of the parent container, while alignSelf deals with the element itself.

```
head:{
   alignSelf:'flex-start',
   // ...other styles
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and `alignItems:'flex-start'`, as indicated in the existing answer?

Comment: `alignItems` is concerned with the children of the parent container, while `alignSelf` deals with the element itself.